# Pandas - Sum columns with the same start of name

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sum columns with the same start of name.

*Example :*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'product':['TV','COMPUTER','SMARTPHONE'],
                 'price_2012':np.random.randint(100,300,3),
                 'price_2013':np.random.randint(100,300,3),
                 'price_2014':np.random.randint(100,300,3),
                 'price_2015':np.random.randint(100,300,3),
                 'price_2016':np.random.randint(100,300,3)})
```

For this exemple i want to create a new column price_2012_2016 equal to the price sum of 2013 to 2016 without list all column.

**PS:** In SAS i do like this : price_2012_2016=sum(of prix_2012-prix-2016);

Cordialy,
Laurent A.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Show us your own attempt and we shall try and help you with it.

Comment: I can have the result by : `df['price_2013-2016']=df['price_2013']+df['price_2014']+df['price_2015']+df['price_2016']`

Comment: `df[['price_' + str(i) for i in range(2013, 2017)]].sum()`?

Comment: Are you after `df.filter(like='price').sum()`?

Comment: with sum(axis=1) the both solutions work, thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

You could simply do the following:

```
df['price_2012_2016'] = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('price_')]].sum(axis=1)
```

This takes the sum of only the columns that start with "price_" within the **df** DataFrame and saves the result as the **price_2012_2016** column. The **axis=1** parameter is for that sum to be computed on the column axis and not the rows, see below:

[image]

Comment: Adding to this post, just in case someone is looking for sum columns with the same ending of column names,

    `df["sum"] = result[[col for col in result.columns if col.endswith('_score')]].sum(axis=1)`