# How to sum same columns (differentiated by suffix) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
total_customers     total_customer_2021-03-31  total_purchases    total_purchases_2021-03-31
1                   10                          4                  6
3                   14                          3                  2
```

Now, I want to sum up the columns row-wise that are the same expect the suffix. I.e the expected output is:

```
total_customers      total_purchases   
11                   10                          
17                   5
```

The issue why I cannot do this manually is because I have 100+ column pairs, so I need an efficient way to do this. Also, the order of columns is not predictable either. What do you recommend?
Thanks!

Comment: You have `total_customers` and `total_customer_`. Do the columns only differ by a date like suffix ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow we need to get an [`Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) of columns so pairs of columns share the same name, then we can [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on `axis=1`:

```
cols = pd.Index(['total_customers', 'total_customers',
                 'total_purchases', 'total_purchases'])

result_df = df.groupby(cols, axis=1).sum()
```

---

With the shown example, we can [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) an optional `s`, followed by underscore, followed by the date format (four numbers`-`two numbers`-`two numbers) with a single `s`. This pattern may need modified depending on the actual column names:

```
cols = df.columns.str.replace(r's?_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$', 's', regex=True)
result_df = df.groupby(cols, axis=1).sum()
```

`result_df`:

```
   total_customers  total_purchases
0               11               10
1               17                5
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'total_customers': [1, 3],
    'total_customer_2021-03-31': [10, 14],
    'total_purchases': [4, 3],
    'total_purchases_2021-03-31': [6, 2]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your dataframe is called df the best solution is:

```
sum_costumers = df[total_costumers] + df[total_costumers_2021-03-31]
sum_purchases = df[total_purchases] + df[total_purchases_2021-03-31]
data = {"total_costumers" : f"{sum_costumers}", "total_purchases" : f"sum_purchases"}
df_total = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=range(1,len(data)))
```

and that will give you the output you want

Comment: the issue is I have 100+ column pairs! I cannot do this manually. What other way do you think makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the headings while coding, to make it shorter, jfi

```
data = {"total_c" : [1,3], "total_c_2021" :[10,14],
    "total_p": [4,3], "total_p_2021": [6,2]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["total_costumers"] = df["total_c"] + df["total_c_2021"]
df["total_purchases"] = df["total_p"] + df["total_p_2021"]
```

If you don't want to see other columns you can drop them

```
df = df.loc[:, ['total_costumers','total_purchases']]
```

NEW PART
So I might have find a starting point for your solution! I dont now the column names but following code can be changed, İf you have a pattern with your column names( it have patterned dates, names, etc). Can you changed the column names with a loop?

```
df['total_customer'] = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('total_c')]].sum(axis=1)
```

And this solution might be helpful for you with some alterations[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333491/pandas-sum-columns-with-the-same-start-of-name)

Comment: the issue is I have 100+ column pairs! I cannot do this manually. What other way do you think makes sense?

Comment: I got it now, I thought it was just 4 columns, Let me have a look again

Comment: So I might find a starting point! I am editing my answer now

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"total_customers": [1, 3], "total_customer_2021-03-31": [10, 14], "total_purchases": [4, 3], "total_purchases_2021-03-31": [6, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

final_df["total_customers"] = df.filter(regex='total_customers*').sum(1)
final_df["total_purchases"] = df.filter(regex='total_purchases*').sum(1)
```

output

```
final_df

    total_customers   total_purchases
0   11                10
1   17                5
```

Comment: the issue is I have 100+ column pairs! I cannot do this manually. What other way do you think makes sense?

Comment: I see, I thought that you have 100+ of the same type of columns like "total_customers*". Let me take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Using @HenryEcker's sample data, and building off of the [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) in the docs, you can create a function and groupby on the column axis:

```py
def get_column(column):
    if column.startswith('total_customer'):
        return 'total_customers'
    return 'total_purchases'

df.groupby(get_column, axis=1).sum()

   total_customers  total_purchases
0               11               10
1               17                5
```